# How to stop overlaying in a positioned stack when keyboard is opened

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, flutter-positioned

I have this `Positioned Stack` and when I open the keyboard to enter in the `textField` it overlays everything and all the widgets move up. How can I stop it and keep them in the same position?

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Graphs'),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          height :  height,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
               Positioned(
                 bottom: height / 2,
                left: 40,
                child: const Text(
                  'test text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: height / 2 - 80,
                child: Column(
                    children : [EquationTextField(onChanged: (input) {
                      setState(() {
                        inEquation = input!;
                      });
                    }, inputScreenContext: context,),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      toggled = !toggled;
                    });
                  },
                child: const Text('Enter'),)]),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

I tried wrapping the `Stack` in a `SingleChildScrollView` but then it gives problems with `Padding` and some other stuff. Another way is appreciated.

Comment: You could try setting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in your Scaffold. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to be fixed when the keyboard is opened, you must use the following code:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false
```

This code is used in the first picture

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,//<-- code is here
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Graphs'),
  ),
```

[image]